# How to set jquery easy UI text box from java servlet

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, jquery-easyui

I have defined in a JSP following tag

```
<input class="easyui-textbox"  multiline="true" editable="false" name="myaction" value="default" style="width: 100%; height: 120px">
```

and I want to be able from servlet code to overwrite the text "default" with some other dynamically String. How can that be done? I tried to set a request attribute and then used a scriptelt inside the textbox element but that did not work (printed always null).
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks